# How can I implement a fastcgi authentication with C++?

Tags: c++, apache, authentication, networking, webserver

I am relatively new in web programming. I wrote a tiny C++ server that generate HTML pages. If I understand correctly, the fastcgi method is the following:

```
                         |                    Site1
                         |  +------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
                         |--|Apache/nginx|---|fastcgi socket|---|My C++ server|
                         |  +------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
                       ........................................................
                         |                    Site2                             
   +-----------------+   |  +------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
===|TCP from Internet|===|--|Apache/nginx|---|fastcgi socket|---|My C++ server|
   +-----------------+   |  +------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
                         |
                         | <-firewall
```

My understanding is the following, please correct me if I am wrong

1. step is that somebody open a Tcp/Http socket to a well known address, ex. http://www.example.com
2. A firewall thing, so a back to back user agent says, he is the example.com and do some traffic routing among web servers
3. Firewall open an other socket to a web server (Apache/nginx) that logs the access and other things..
4. Web server open a new socket to my C++ server
5. My C++ server got that fastcgi socket, I accept the connection, and I start to poll the i/o events on that connection
6. When data is arriving on that fastcgi connection, I read it and parse the content as HTTP header and HTTP payload

So my question is how can I authenticate or with other words recognize a user? So is it true that 1 connection is 1 user? Should I start a state machine on every connection that handle the login/logout states? So when a new connection is accepted the state is "logged out", and I send back a registration form, and when i got a user/pass the connection state step to "logged in" and the server send the personalized content.

My C++ server is based on [server1 - a c++ network server/client framework](http://code.google.com/p/server1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question requires books worth of answers.

5 & 6 are correct but the web server will handle all that.

You really should focus on a small achievable goal. Let's start with fastcgi authentication. Search using "authentication Cookies" and that should get you a start on one part of your answer.